# How to handle exceptions in Tasks with debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception, task-parallel-library

I studied [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx), as well as some questions/answers on SO regarding this topic, but cannot figure why below code does not work (in a sample console app).

AggregateException is expected to be thrown, according to MSDN, which would contain one inner exception with `hello` message. Instead, this `hello` exception is unhandled. It happens when inside a debugger.

If you press continue or run standalone, it works as expected. Is there any way to avoid pressing continue all the time in VS? After all, whatever is within a `Try...Catch` block is considered *handled* in a single threaded programming model. Otherwise, debugging could be a nightmare.

**VB.NET**

```vb
Sub Main()
  Try
    Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf TaskThatThrowsException).Wait()
  Catch ex As AggregateException
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString) 'does not get here until you hit Continue
  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TaskThatThrowsException()
  Throw New Exception("hello") 'exception was unhandled
End Sub
```

**C#**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      try {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskThatThrowsException).Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); //never gets here                
      }
    }

    static void TaskThatThrowsException() {
      throw new Exception("hello"); //exception was unhandled            
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: Set the debugger to halt on all exceptions. Where does it stop? It should stop in `TaskThatThrowsException` and on `Wait`.

Comment: @usr: even now it stops at `Throw New Exception("hello")` line, checking all Thrown does not make it better. I would like it not stop at that, and rather process Console.WriteLine. Otherwise, debugging could be a nightmare.

Comment: Exceptions from tasks do not appear in StartNew, only in .Wait(). Dim myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(...) Try MyTask.Wait() Catch...

Comment: @adrianm: In the above code Wait() is also inside `Try...Catch`. But I tried a standalone version, i.e. `MyTask.Wait` - same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting "Enable Just My Code" has an effect on this. Under Tools->Options, Debugging->General->enable Just My Code.  If you have it turned on, it will consider the exception unhandled if *your* code doesn't handle it.  Try turning this option off.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

Comment: +1. So it seems like this approach is recommended by Microsoft, for this specific case. Guess I should read MSDN more carefully next time, cause I'm sure I glanced quickly through this particular page before asking this question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because you're misunderstanding what the Visual Studio dialog is saying.

The exception is “user unhandled”, because there is no user code that catches it (the original `Exception`), it's catched by TPL. So, if you let the debugger continue, or if you run your application without the debugger, you will see the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: +1. Well, with normal exceptions, they are considered handled, if within a `Try...Catch` block (and the type corresponds, and not rethrown, of course). How else am I supposed to debug my application? Press continue all the time in similar cases? Is there any way to make VS not catch these exceptions when debugging?

Comment: @Neolisk Debug->Exceptions->Uncheck Thrown

Comment: @Neolisk, This is just a guess: at some point I recall that under Tools->Options, the setting for Debugging->General->Enable Just My Code made a difference.  I thought that if you have it turned on, that it will consider the exception unhandled if *your* code doesn't handle it.  Try turning this option off.  (I didn't verify this).

Comment: @MattSmith: Amazing, you found it! Now it's working as expected. Not sure which other consequences I will encounter though, by turning that option off, but hoping for good, as usual. Please post as an answer to be accepted. If you can elaborate about consequences (maybe, some examples), would be nice to know.

Comment: The "Enable Just My Code" is mainly a convenience feature to allow you to debug into only code you've written.  I don't think that you'll experience any adverse affects from turning it off (I keep it off all the time).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.100).aspx