# Exception not caught in Task.Run

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task

I'm trying to catch an exception thrown by a method (`GetMoreCodes`) run by a `Task`, but when debugging the exception is never handled and the catch block is never hit. Tried different techniques (in particular with/without await). This code is in an (`async`) button event handler.

```
try
{
    // Task.Run(() => GetMoreCodes(CodeBufferMaxSize));
    // await Task.Run(() => GetMoreCodes(0));
    await Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("test!"); });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: " + ex);
}
```

This looks to me like most examples I saw here and in blogs, in particular in this one (http://blog.stephencleary.com/ - big thanks @stephen-cleary).

For now, I only want the application not to crash and log an error if any.
Am I missing something?

Comment: what happens if you put a break point on and step through it?

Comment: Task has properties to get the exception that occured inside. To check exception you can just do something like `Task t = Task.Run ( () => { throw new Exception("test!"); }); while(!t.IsCompleted) Application.DoEvents(); t.Exception;`

Comment: Try this link. I think it may be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990998/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-tasks-with-debugger

Comment: @m.rogalski : I'm not an expert programmer but fixing issues with Application.DoEvents() is not recommended...?

Comment: @sheavens : It worked, but I don't understand why and what would the impact in production without the debugger.

Comment: @supafly it is not recommended but for testing everything is allowed

Comment: @m.rogalski Using broken and inconstant code that's likely to behave erratically and unpredictably is not a good way to test behavior.  That's just how you end up confusing yourself and causing problems for yourself trying to figure out why the code you write to figure something *else* out is doing broken things.

Comment: You must have a problem in code not shown.  The code shown will result in the exception being caught.

Comment: Are u using the debugger? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282414/try-catch-wrap-around-task-run-not-handling-exception) might cause the problem too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
await Task.Run(() => {
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("test!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catched");
    }
});
```

Why not just catched in the `Task.Run()` ?

If you want to catch it in Console.Application with your code you can do it like this. But t.Wait() is blocking the UI Thread and waits for the Task to finish.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Task t = TestError();
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catched");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static async Task TestError()
    {
            // Task.Run(() => GetMoreCodes(CodeBufferMaxSize));
            // await Task.Run(() => GetMoreCodes(0));
            await Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("test!"); });
    }
```

Comment: First proposal works and seems to be the right way to do it. If you could explain why exception should be handled in that code and not in the code creating the thread it would be cool :) thanks!

Comment: @supafly It's not, and it *will* work to have the awaiting code catch the exception.